# Sql select into categories

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have table name locinvaisle and column name region. I need to select the values into the categories of "Peninsular", "Sabah" & "Sarawak" which i can select the categories as column. What is the sql query to archieve that?

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CadMp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select values-needed, region from table_name group by region
```

If you want to know more about group by in sql go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this select query

```
Select region from table_name where region in ('Peninsular','Sabah','Sarawak')
```

Comment: can i write somewhat like this?e.g : select region as P, region as Sbh, region as swk  
from locinvaisle 
where region in ('a','b') and region in ('c','d') and region in ('e','f')

Comment: i tried but it shows no values. maybe u can write for me the proper sql as my expected result(pic link) above.